# Is there a naturally occurring cycle I can use to synthesize a cycle of light (which impacts the magic of the reality)?

Tags: science-based, magic, light, balancing-magic-systems

This cycle of light interacts with the flow of energy and willpower manipulated by the beings of this reality. Their magic is evolutionary/adaptive, and so the light cycle is a "natural" product of various environments/settings in this reality. It impacts flora/fauna, and has affected the adaptation of various peoples' magicks throughout history. Also, this reality is a severed half from our present-day world.

Edit:
I'm interested in a light cycle I can adapt for various elemental powers, sourced from the Chinese elements (wood, metal, wind, water, fire). It's something that is tapped into by the people for various traditions, as well as modes of survival.

The setting is somewhat similar to our world, but instead of artificial constructs  (i.e., automobiles, modern home construction, general industrialization), magic is the means of altering reality. There is only one moon and sun, but I have yet to determine how time runs here. I don't want it too far off from our reality for plot reasons.

So I need a basic cycle I can alter for celestial and ordinary means.

Comment: Sunrise and sunset? Perhaps we need to know a bit more about your setting.

Comment: I agree with Schwern, we need more details. Could be the sunrise or sunset, could be another planet being alligned, could be a comet passing by in a eliptical orbit, could be a bunch of things. It's better if we knew hor much of time you need between cycles

Comment: This is a very vague question! There are plenty of natural light cycles. Day/night, moon cycling from full to new moon, light and dark phases of photosynthesis, planet's orbit around the sun and aphelion/perihelion distances from the sun, sun spots, bioluminence, hell heat signatures of animals and plants could even work etc etc etc. What exactly is the problem you trying to solve? What you described is too vague to even understand what sort of cycle you are after...

Comment: Realistically only day/night cycle and variation in the amount of light with the seasons would have such a large effect. So just pick the length of cycle that fits better.

Comment: @Surian Is this detailed enough?

Comment: @EveryBitHelps Do I need more detail?

Comment: The details you added are generally interesting, but I think they're looking for details such as what makes light different in this other world, how it interacts, how people tap into it, etc. What does light actually do, apart from illumine? Also, if the obvious day / night, lunar monthly & seasonal / yearly cycles won't cut it, why not?

Comment: The new details don’t really make this more answerable, in my opinion. The only cycles of light in nature are based on the sun. That’s not something your people will casually alter to, say, build a house. Life energy comes from the sun. It is the sole driver. Even moon and stars are reflections of or hidden by the sun. Your question seems to ask for something else **but gives us no example of what you’re looking for**.

Comment: I agree with elemtilas. If the obvious day/night, lunar or seasonal yearly cycles don't cut it, what sort of light cycle are you after? You haven't explained why you are Not using these options which would help provide insight into what alternatives could be suggested.